# Use Drupal views to generate contact Reports in Civicrm

Tags: drupal, civireport, drupal-views

I have several different types of report's layouts/formats to print for Civicrm contacts. I know that, we can generate reports by 'Report' menu in Civicrm.

But i want some suggestion about how much it will be easy to generate reports using Drupal Views. Because here, we have an option to override the reports templates easily. Isn't ?

Please let me know if it will cause any error in future.

Answer (score 6):

If you prefer a solution which is editable via a web GUI, then Drupal Views are a great flexible approach. We use them extensively. You may hit the occasional limitation (either a "Views-ism" or a lack of support for some minor feature) but that's rare. If you are comfortable with Views, you'll be right at home :)

If you prefer writing SQL and are comfortable with PHP, a CiviCRM Report is a solution which offers you a lot of customisation, and building extensions is much easier now with [`civix`](https://github.com/totten/civix).

Comment: Yeah. But is there anything which can creates problem in future, if we'll use Drupal Views instead of Civicrm Reports ?

Comment: It's possible either way. I *think* our experience would be that we've had to do less work upgrading Views than Reports. Not a scientific assessment :)

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.  It's very common to use Drupal Views to display contacts' information, either to the public (as in a directory) or internally.  You'll see CiviCRM contacts as a option when creating your view, and you can create relationships to contributions, memberships, etc.  Modules that extend Views will help, too.

Read more about it at [book.civicrm.org](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/website-integration/integrating-with-drupal/)

Comment: Yeah correct, that's why i was thinking to use Drupal Views. And I already, saw that link but just want to go deeper to compare Drupal Views over Civicrm Reports.  It'll be appreciated if you can provide me any advanced reference on how to extend Civicrm Reports features in Drupal. Thanks :)